# Get the highest number of a .txt file in c#

Tags: c#

I have a directory with files such as
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt

How could I get the highest number that is in the directory of the .txt file name?

Heres what i tried

```
  DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Public\BotMakerLoggerSite\Logs\" + token + @"\");
            int highest = 0;
                 foreach (var file in d.GetFiles(" *.txt"))
                 {
                     string a = file.Name.Replace(".txt", "");
                     int b = Convert.ToInt32(a);
                     if (b >= highest)
                     {
                         highest = b;
                     }

               }
            try
            {
                t = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\BotMakerLoggerSite\Logs\" + token + @"\" + highest + ".txt");

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\BotMakerLoggerSite\Logs\" + token + @"\" + highest + ".txt", t + Environment.NewLine + e.Source + " | " + DateTime.Now + " | " + e.Severity + " : " + e.Message + "=" + highest);
```

Comment: What have you tried doing? And how is it not working?

Comment: @UnholySheep I am trying to get all the files in the directory and covert their names to ints then compare them. My goal is that if i had a mix of numbers 1-100 in the directory as the numbers for txt file names I want to grab the highest one.

Comment: @LoganRisen then show us what you have tried, and we will tell you whats wrong with it

Comment: i updated my post with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help. It uses a regular expression to extract the number part of the filename; in this case it will look for numbers at the start of the file, which appears to be what you want. If it's something like "my51st.txt", it wont return 51. The regular expression part is the line:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(name, "\\d+");
```

where d+ means extract one or more digits at the beginning of the string.

Here's the code:

```
        var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
        var numberList = new List<int>();
        int number;

        foreach (var name in fileNames) {
            Match m = Regex.Match(name, "\\d+"); // this gets the number at beginning of filename
            var isNumber = Int32.TryParse(m.ToString(), out number);

            if(isNumber)
                numberList.Add(number);
        }

        var highest = numberList.OrderByDescending(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
```

EDIT: Refactored into more efficient code, doesn't build an entire array and then gets the highest number. Also uses out variable declaration from C#7:

```
        var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
        int? highest = null;

        foreach (var name in fileNames) {
            var m = Regex.Match(name, "^\\d+"); // this gets the number at beginning of filename
            Int32.TryParse(m.ToString(), out int number);

            if (number > (highest ?? 0))
                highest = number;
        }

        // The string 'result' will either contain the number or the message depending on whether it is still null or not.
        var result = (highest?.ToString() ?? "No Number Found");
```

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: Excelllent! Have just added an edit to reflect new out variable feature in C# 7.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this approach:

```
Func<string, int?> tryParse = x =>
{
    int r;
    if (int.TryParse(x, out r))
    {
        return r;
    }
    return null;
};

int highest =
    new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Public\BotMakerLoggerSite\Logs\" + token + @"\")
        .GetFiles()
        .Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.Name))
        .Select(x => tryParse(x))
        .Where(x => x.HasValue)
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
        .Max();
```

---

Alternative `tryParse`:

```
int? tryParse(string text) => int.TryParse(text, out int value) ? (int?)value : null;
```

Comment: This one is best because you can change the inline function to also parse out parts of the name, like (**x.Split('.')[1]**) in: 

`if (int.TryParse(x.Split('.')[1], out r))
    {
        return r;
    }
`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps you may try to achieve this:

1. Define an integer variable with value [`Int32.MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Get the file names in a directory as an `IEnumerable<string>`: [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. Loop over the file names and for each file get the name without the extension: [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)
4. Try to parse the filename to an integer: [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)
5. If parsing succeeds and the resulting number is bigger than the integer variable you declared earlier, then set the integer variable to this value
6. When the loop completes the integer variable will hold the desired value or `Int32.MinValue` (if non of the file names were able to be parsed to integers)